# Timeout message while parsing json from a url

Tags: android

**What i am trying to do**: I am trying to parse a value from URL `http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/` and display a value in the `textview` on click of a button

**What is happening**: I am not able to show the result in the fragment though i can see the log that the value has correctly been parsed.

***How can i resolve this ! !***

---

**apache_http_connection.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/apacheBtnId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ParseData" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/apacheTxtId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="MyText"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**ApacheHttpConnection.java**

```
public class ApacheHttpConnection extends Fragment {


    // JSON Node names 
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

    String name;

    private String errMsg="";
    private static boolean isErr=false;
    String url="http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";
    private TextView apacheTxtId;
    private Button apacheBtnId;

    //Creating a new instance
    public static ApacheHttpConnection newInstance(){
        ApacheHttpConnection fragment=new ApacheHttpConnection();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.apache_http_connection, container, false);

        apacheTxtId=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.apacheTxtId);
        apacheBtnId=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.apacheBtnId);

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        apacheBtnId.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new LongOperation().execute("");
            }
        });
    }


    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        String webData;
        JSONArray contacts = null;



        @Override 
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                webData=doConnection(url);
                if (webData != null) { 
                    // Getting JSON Object node 
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(webData);
                    // Getting JSON Array node 
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS); 
                    // Getting data from Object node
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(1); 
                    name = c.getString(TAG_NAME); 
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                publishProgress(1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                publishProgress(2);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                publishProgress(3);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                publishProgress(4);
            }
            return null; 
        } 

        @Override 
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        } 

        @Override 
        protected void onPreExecute() {} 

        @Override 
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            if(values[0]==1){
                if(isErr==true){
                    DlgUniversalError.showQuitAlert(getActivity(),errMsg);
                }
            }
            else if(values[0]==2){
                if(isErr==true){
                    DlgUniversalError.showQuitAlert(getActivity(),errMsg);
                }
            }
            else if(values[0]==3){
                if(isErr==true){
                    DlgUniversalError.showQuitAlert(getActivity(),errMsg);
                }
            }
            else if(values[0]==4){
                if(isErr==true){
                    DlgUniversalError.showQuitAlert(getActivity(),errMsg);
                }
            }   
        }
    } 



    public String doConnection(String url) throws ClientProtocolException,IOException,Exception{

        HttpGet httpget=null;
        String mContent=null;
        HttpClient Client=null;

        try {
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 500);

            Client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
            httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            mContent = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(isErr==false){
                errMsg=e.getLocalizedMessage();
                isErr=true;
            }
            throw e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(isErr==false){
                errMsg=e.getLocalizedMessage();
                isErr=true;
            }
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(isErr==false){
                errMsg=e.getLocalizedMessage();
                isErr=true;
            }
            throw e;
        }   
        return mContent;
    }

}
```

**log**::

```
09-15 12:59:25.609: D/<--MyResult-->(1128): Johnny Depp
```

**Output**::

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You have to return a value from doInBackground() like so:

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground()");
        try {
            webData = doConnection(url);
            if (webData != null) {
                // Getting JSON Object node 
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(webData);
                // Getting JSON Array node 
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);
                // Getting data from Object node
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(1);
                name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground() contacts, name: "+contacts+", "+name);

                //HERE :)
                return name;
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            publishProgress(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            publishProgress(2);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            publishProgress(3);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            publishProgress(4);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

2) And then you have to actually set the value of name to your TextView

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (apacheTxtId != null){
            apacheTxtId.setText(result);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yup ! ... that's the solution right ! ...... So If we are printing a value in the `onPostExecute()` ..... We have to return the value from `doInBackground()`as you mentioned in order for the `OnPostExecute()` to to update the UI-Thread ?

Comment: you dont have to set a return value for doInBackground() way you did this is ok. besides you already have a return value which is name

Comment: Devrath - yes, return the value in doInBackground() but update the UI element from main thread in onPostExecute(). @santalu - if he does not return the value, it will be a null value returned.

Comment: he has already a global variable "name" and he's setting  name = c.getString(TAG_NAME); inside doInBackground() method. so it doesn't matter whether he's returning null from doInBackground() cause he already retrieved what he want

Comment: Yup, you're right, saw that now. But to hash this out, I'm setting the textView with the  parameter `result`.

Answer (score 1):

just set textview in your asynctask onPostExecute() method:

for ex:

```
 @Override 
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                apacheTxtId.setText(name);
            }
```

Note: i did this without using onProgressUpdate() method. it must be something wrong over there